# Android Studio: Null Reference Exception - Resource not found

Tags: android, list, exception, null

I know there are many questions like this however all of the other answers are not applicable as they are already accounted for - in my activity I create a list and am trying to add an item however it gives me

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.prprmpt.prprmpt/com.prprmpt.prprmpt.activ_Nav}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
```

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
list<class_article> articles;

public List<class_article> articles;
    SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activ_nav);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        class_article newClass = new class_article();
        newClass.title = "spazmonkee";

        articles = new ArrayList<>();
        articles.add(newClass);
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activeFrag), articles.size(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Is `R.id.toolbar` inside `R.layout.activ_nav`?

Comment: cross check your id's again

Comment: Somewhere you are using R.string.some_string or @string/some_string where some_string is not declared inside strings.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<class_article> articles;
    SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activ_nav);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        class_article newClass = new class_article();
        newClass.title = "spazmonkee";

        articles = new ArrayList<>();
        articles.add(newClass);
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activeFrag), articles.size()+"", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

It will now work! `articles.size()` returns `int` so `Snackbar.make()` will consider it as string resource id, that caused the exception. So parse it as string.

I just edited your`Snackbar.make()` statement.

Try the above code and let me know!

Comment: Wow.
Such a simple answer.
Thankyou very much!

Comment: @OscarCooke-Abbott Please upvote and mark the answer as working solution. You are welcome!